# run a script or sanity check against outgoing emails in outlook 2010

Tags: outlook

Is there a way to setup Outlook 2010 to run a script or some other form of sanity-check when you attempt to SEND messages from the client?  My specific situation is that I use the same outlook client for multiple accounts (work, gmail, VPS server, etc) and I've found myself a couple of times sending emails "from" the wrong account.

In a perfect world I'd want to be able to write a script with logic something like the following:

```
when (I hit send)
  if (the "source" account is "myuserid@gmail.com")  then 
    if (there are addresses in TO or CC that match "work.com")  then
      pop up a dialog box that says:
         "You appear to be sending email to work.com from gmail.com - do you really want to do this?"
            if yes, then send it and return
            if no, go back to the message compose window
```

that way, I'd have to actually very intentionally use a non-work email address to send email to the work people (which is rare in my particular case)

Answer (score 0):

Try [SendUsingAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) to read the "source" account in [ItemSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx).